# Is it correct to say : "Can you confirm this email reach you properly ?"

Tags: grammaticality

When I write an email to someone, I like to get a confirmation that the guy in front received and read properly my email.

So I'd like to know if :

> Can you confirm this email reach properly.

Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're perhaps looking for something like *Please confirm receipt of this email/letter*. Note that "an email reaching the recipient" is not the same thing as "the recipient having received and read the email".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your request is actually an analog of the following question, with a *that*-clause, with the word **that** omitted:

> Can you please confirm that this email {verb} you?
>
> Can you please confirm this email {verb} you?

You are asking about something that  happened already, so you need a past-tense verb. Compare:

> Can you confirm (that) the train **departed** on time yesterday?

We don't use the bare infinitive **depart** in the *that*-clause; rather we use a tensed (finite) verb, **depart*ed***.

> Can you confirm (that) the email **reached** you?
>
> Can you please confirm that this email **has reached** you?

Answer (score 3):

It should be past tense. And "reach" in this case is transitive, that is, you have to say who or what it reached.

So, "Can you confirm this email reached you properly?"

It's more common to make it a request rather than a question. And "properly" is pretty much implied. So the more common phrasing would be:

"Please confirm this email reached you."